# How to make lower output viewing panel in Sublime Text reappear after text search?

Tags: python-3.x, sublimetext3, sublimetext2

I use sublime text for python. I am using default setup so after I run (F7) the script, the result/output of the python script will appear in the bottom viewing panel.

But the problem is, during the script execution, I often need to work on the same script and sometime needs to search a word in the main programming panel, and as soon as I go `Ctrl+F` to search, the bottom viewing panel disappear. How can I make it reappear so I can see my results after the script has finished running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sublime only allows a single panel to be open at a time, which is why when you open the find panel, the build output goes away.

You can get the build results to re-appear in the following ways:

1. Select `Tools > Build Results > Show Build Results` from the main menu
2. Select `Build: Show Results` from the command palette
3. Click on the panel switcher and select `Build Results` from the pop up menu; the panel switcher is the icon all the way to the left in the status bar at the bottom of the window:

   [image: Panel Switcher Location]

You can also create a key binding like the following (swap the key for something more appropriate for you) to open the panel with a key instead as well:

```json
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+alt+shift+b"],
    "command": "show_panel",
    "args": {
        "panel": "output.exec",
    },
},
```